# tapku initialize sunday as first day

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tapku

in my calendar project i have a tapku calendar which displays monday on the very left. In America however, Sunday is usually on the left, so tapku has a method

```
- (id)initWithSunday:(BOOL)sundayFirst
```

so that can happen. However this method is used in the previous view controller, that controller initializes the tapkuViewController and then segues over. However, I start my project in the tapku view controller. So how do I set Sunday on the left?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a tapkuViewController in the project? Is that the actual name?

Comment: no that's not the actual name, but basically its the view controller that has the calendar

Comment: What is the actual name? It's hard to help you without knowing which controller you're talking about. I'm not that familiar with tapku.

Comment: It is called ViewContoller